# End balance in a year with a 5% annual return with monthly $1000 contributions in the beginning of the month

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the end balance earned in one year based on $1000 monthly contributions and $0 starting balance on a 5% annual return.

So each year I should be contributing $12,000 and the interest that I earn should have equaled $322.58 making the end balance $12,322.58.

Here is my code so far but the end balance that I am getting is only 12050.

```
count = 0
current_savings = 0
r = 0.05

while count < 12:
    current_savings += 1000
    Monthly_interest = (current_savings*r)/12
    Final_amount = current_savings + Monthly_interest
    count += 1

print(Final_amount)
```

Comment: You need to update `current_savings` each month.  Don't create a separate `Final_amount`.  The final is just the final value of `current_savings`'.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's intentional, but the monthly compound interest formula is (1+r)^(1/12)-1 where r is the annual interest, also if your code returns an integer instead of a float I would suggest writting current_savings = 0.0 so that python recognizes it as a float

Comment: Also if you're interested in a formula that doesn't require loops you can use 1000 * ((1+r)^n-1)/r where r is your interest rate and n is the number of periods so in your case n =12 and r = (1.05)^1/12-1 note that this formula calculates interest before depositing money if you want the opposite, multiply the formula by 1+r

Answer (score 0):

Note that most banks will compute the interest BEFORE adding the new deposit.  You'll have to decide what order is right for you.

```
current_savings = 0
r = 0.05

for _ in range(12):
    current_savings += 1000
    Monthly_interest = (current_savings*r)/12
    current_savings += Monthly_interest

print(current_savings)
```